# How do I apply darkTheme in gedit?

Tags: linux, theme, gedit

[image]

I am using a Linux beta in chromebook and gedit with plugins.

I want to make the gedit theme all dark. As you can see in the screenshot, I managed to change the theme, but the file browser and the terminal in Gedit won't turn dark. I already changed the color in Preferences → Font & Color.

Comment: You need to change your global gnome theme to dark.

Comment: I am not using gnome right now. I only have linux terminal. Is there other way not using gnome? (I may be wrong because I don't know much about linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LXAppearance has the least amount of dependencies and it configure GTK2/3 themes.

Other tools: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK#Configuration_tools

Configure manually by editing text files (does not always work):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK#Basic_theme_configuration

As to what dark/black themes are available - it's your distro specific.